# iOS: Facing issue while upgrading from cordova 2.2.0 to 2.3.0

Tags: ios, cordova

I have been developing a phonegap iOS application with cordova 2.2.0 version. Now I want to upgrade to cordova 2.3.0 due to some reason. For doing so, I have taken phonegap documentation as a reference where they have mentioned step-by-step approach.

I was able to do everything except the following step

**Convert your Cordova.plist file to config.xml, by running the script bin/cordova_plist_to_config_xml on your project file.**

How to run that script and where should I run that. I have run that in terminal but got the following error

bash: No such file or directory found

Please help me in this.

Comment: Did you use your project file as parameter while running the script?

Comment: example: ./bin/cordova_plist_to_config_xml 
/Path/To/My/Project/File.xcodeproj

Comment: From which folder should I run this command from terminal? Do I have to path of my .xcodeproj file?

Comment: if you are finding it difficult, just move configurations manually from plist to config.xml file. Its better if u dont have too many configurations.

Comment: Thanks .......  I am actually now creating a new project from scratch. And then copying the required stuff into config.xml

Answer (score 0):

This script is for converting your cordova 2.2 Plist to cordova 2.3 XMLConfig...
In 2.3 version it requires xmlconfig for the corresponding normal plist..so we have to convert our plist to xmlconfig..The following script will do it.

The syntax of this script is

```
./cordova_plist_to_config_xml /Path to your Xcode project/
```

example:

```
./cordova_plist_to_config_xml /Users/shabab/Desktop/Plancentral/Plancentral.xcodeproj
```

Comment: Did this work for you Rashmi?  I'm having difficulties getting this to run still...What path in relation to the project is this command executed? And must the plist file be located in a certain area of the project?